# Select and read sockets (Unix)

Tags: sockets, unix

I have an intermittent problem with a telnet based server on Unix (the problem crops up on both AIX and Linux).
The server opens two sockets, one to a client telnet session, and one to a program running on the same machine as the server. The idea is that the data is passed through the server to and from this program.

The current setup has a loop using select to wait for a "read" file descriptor to become available, then uses select to wait for a "write" file descriptor to become available.

Then the program reads from the incoming file descriptor, then processes the data before writing to the outgoing descriptor.

The snippet below shows what is going on. The problem is that very occasionally the read fails, with errno being set to ECONNRESET or ETIMEDOUT. Neither of these are codes documented by read, so where are they coming from?

The real question is, how can I either stop this happening, or handle it gracefully?
Could doing two selects in a row be the problem?

The current handling behaviour is to shut down and restart. One point to note is that once this happens it normally happens three or four times, then clears up. The system load doesn't really seem to be that high (it's a big server).

```
        if (select(8, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
                {
                break;
                }
        if (select(8, NULL, &writeset, NULL, NULL) < 0)
                {
                break;
                }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readset)
        && FD_ISSET(fdout, &writeset))
                {
                if ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFFSIZE)) < 0)
                        {
                        /* This sometimes fails with errno = 
                           ECONNRESET or ETIMEDOUT */
                        break;
                        }
                }
```

Comment: You know, you can combine both of these `select` calls into one. also, the first argument to `select` should be the maximum fd in the set + 1, rather than 8. Also, is stdin a socket?

Comment: STDIN_FILENO returning ETIMEDOUT is unusual. Are you doing anything special to it ? (redirection, fcntls etc) ?

Comment: I suggest you start by implementing both of Hasturkun's suggestions, select can be quite temperamental if not treated properly.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that putting them both into one select could return when only one fd is ready? I.e. the write might not be ready at the same time as the read.

Comment: Also, 8 is fine in this case - bad style I know but it's not my code. Those two fd's are 4 and 5 respectively.

Comment: And yes, I am doing something special - the stdin and stdout are duplicated and closed to make the pass-though bit work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comments in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/mips/include/asm/errno.h on lines 85 and 98: these basically say there was a network connection reset or time out. Check and see if there are timeouts you can adjust on the remote network program, or send some periodic filler bytes to ensure that the connection stays awake consistently. You may just be victim of an error in the network transit path between the remote client and your local server (this happens to me when my DSL line hiccups).

EDIT: not sure what the downvote is for. The [man page for read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) explicitly says:

*Other errors may occur, depending on the object connected to fd.*

The error is probably occuring in the `select`, not in the `read`: you're not checking errors after the `select`, you're just proceeding to the `read`, which will fail if the `select` returned an error. I'm betting if you check the errno value after the `select` call you'll see the errors: you don't need to wait for the `read` to see the errors.

Comment: You'll probably get another -1 for your edit, re: where the error comes from. a failing `read` will overwrite `errno`

Comment: I am reasonably sure it's not a "real" timeout, as it happens instantly on connection.

Comment: The various section 7 manual pages document the addition error codes that read (and other system calls) can return on different types of sockets.  see `socket(7)`, `ip(7)`, `tcp(7)` and/or `unix(7)`.   Note that the select call generally WONT give you the error code; it will return success, meaning a read on the socket won't block